# Blurring text in uilabel ios in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uilabel

I have TableViewCell and in this cell UILabel.
I init cell like this:

```
TableViewCell *cell = [self.TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = kColorAppYellow;
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.imageViewCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.imageViewCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNamed"];
    cell.imageViewArrow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNamed"];
    cell.label.text = @"bla-Bla-bla";
}
```

Code For second and others cell

```
  if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    cell.imageViewCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.imageViewCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNamed"];
    cell.imageViewArrow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNamed"];
    cell.label.text = @"bla-Bla-bla";
}
```

First cell has normal text, but 2nd and 3rd has blurring text in Label, then 4th has normal text... on one screen i have only 3 visible cell

How can i get normal text in all cell?

EDIT: I solve this problem. Move content from TableView to CollectionView

Comment: If you are having problems with the 2nd and 3rd cell, why did you only post code for the 1st cell?

Comment: And why do you mention a 4th cell and then state the table only has 3 rows? Or do you mean the table is only tall enough to show 3 rows at a time?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I  mean the table is only tall enough to show 3 rows at a time

Comment: Your question can't be answered without more details about how you produce all cells and how they look (I mean blurring text) on the screen.